# PHP - Sharing session between multiple subdomains

Tags: php, session-variables

I have a website with multiple applications on subdomains and i want to share some SESSION variables between them.

I tried this:

```
$some_name = session_name("somename-session");
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.sub.example.eu');
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.sub.example.eu' );
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime ', 2678400); // Set expiration to 1 month
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 2678400); // Set expiration to 1 month
ini_set('suhosin.session.cryptdocroot', "Off");
ini_set('suhosin.cookie.cryptdocroot', "Off");
```

With all of those things, it doesn't work, PHPSESSID are the same in both websites but variable aren't transmitted.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Well... you've got a typo in the question which I assume isn't in the code or it would have just failed outright at: `ini_set('session.cookie_domain', ''.sub.example.eu' );`

Comment: @CD001 That's an error in copy/paste to that post sry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem found:**

My subdomains are on different apache servers so sessions vars can't be shared. I'll use database storage with unique vars in cookies to share my variables.