# Session Loss and Redirection Issue Between Subdomain and Domain

Tags: php, session, cookies, subdomain

I'm experiencing a session management issue on my website, https://www.progressiveai.org, which has a subdomain and the main domain: https://auth.progressiveai.org and https://www.progressiveai.org. When a user logs in on https://auth.progressiveai.org, a session is created, but when they navigate to https://www.progressiveai.org/Talk, they are redirected to https://auth.progressiveai.org as if they were not logged in. This problem persists even after clearing browser cookies and site data. How can I ensure consistent session management and prevent this redirection issue when moving between Sub-Domain and Domain?

But, when I enter in Incognito, log in and redirect to https://www.progressiveai.org/Talk it works fine. When I go on progressiveai.org/Talk, cookies and site data, delete all of them and go to https://auth.progressiveai.org to re-login. Would you look at that! https://www.progressiveai.org/Talk redirects me to https://auth.progressiveai.org just like I was never logged in!

Here is the PHP code of https://www.progressiveai.org/Talk :

```php
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['SESSION_EMAIL'])) {
    header("Location: https://auth.progressiveai.org");
    die();
}

include '../config.php';

$email = $_SESSION['SESSION_EMAIL'];

// Create a prepared statement
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = ?");
if ($stmt === false) {
    die("Error: " . mysqli_error($conn));
}

// Bind the email parameter to the statement
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $email);

// Execute the statement
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

// Get the result set
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

if ($result) {
    // Fetch a single row as an associative array
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
?>
```

And here is some of the PHP code of https://auth.progressiveai.org :

```php
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.progressiveai.org');
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['SESSION_EMAIL'])) {
    header("Location: https://auth.progressiveai.org/redirect");
    die();
}

// Include your database configuration file
include '../config.php';

// Replace this query with your actual database query
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");
if ($stmt === false) {
    die("Error: " . mysqli_error($conn));
}

$email = ''; // Initialize email variable

// Bind the email parameter to the statement
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $email);

// Execute the statement
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

// Get the result set
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

if ($result) {
    // Fetch a single row as an associative array
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

?>
...
```

If you have any questions or concerns about this question ask me. Thanks in Advance.

### NOTE: None of the following articles I found on Stack Overflow solved my specific problem:

[Sharing session variables between multiple subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153716/sharing-session-variables-between-multiple-subdomains)

[PHP Sharing Session between multiple subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45148387/php-sharing-session-between-multiple-subdomains)

[Can't share PHP sessions between subdomain and main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50076980/cant-share-php-sessions-between-subdomain-and-main)

I have reviewed these articles, but unfortunately, the solutions presented did not resolve the session management issue I am encountering on my website.

Comment: You would think that [the code in this note](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php#94961) would work. So a `session_set_cookie_params()` before **-- all --** of your `session_start()` calls, and then start by logging in.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, that you for your comment, but if I go on https://www.progressiveai.org/Talk after logging in and delete all the cookies and then attempt to sign in again via https://auth.progressiveai.org and enter https://www.progressiveai.org/Talk it will simply redirect my to the auth page again because it didn't detect that I have already logged in.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Comment: @Dharman! This is not my existing complete PHP code, as I mentioned earlier this is a snipper of the code I already acknowledge the existence of SQL Indections.

Comment: If you acknowledge it then you should fix it. Why was it written like that to begin with? Anyway it's off the point. We always give a warning no matter what the scenario, just in case

Comment: @ADyson, this code is a snippet and it is not prepared for the public, I just want to test why this happening with the cookies. Before the full release of the Website, I'm sure to have most of my code updated. But, we are getting of topic now.

Comment: You posted the code publicly which means it's prepared for public. If it's not then please update the code in question to show the actual code.

Comment: People copy code from Stack Overflow all the time. One of the most pervasive problem we encounter is not using parameterized prepared statements, because people copy bad code. That why we always have to warn about this and ask to edit the code.

Comment: As to your reaction, I assume that happens when the code looks like it is in your question? You never said you tried the suggested note. Also, I find your instructions quite confusing, but that might be me... Anyway, why should we register? You can simply echo the `session_id()`, after `session_start()`, at the top of the page, so we can see which session we are in, in each subdomain. Echoing something for debugging purposes is quite normal.

Comment: People copy code without permission this is why I post code that is either not completed or has errors that I already know the solution for. I don't want people to know more about the structure of my Website as in the future it will house more important info. This is why I don't provide the complete code. Sharing code can also produce vulnerabilities in some parts of my Website. But, I want to know how to solve my real problem.

Comment: I think it is possible to combine both: Write correct code and not reveal to much about your site. Also, [security through obfuscation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) as a strategy is not recommended, [security by design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_by_design) is. If you really want to protect your website, you could have used the example.com domain.

Comment: Why do we get out of topic? Let me edit the post with the Anti-SQL Injection Code if this is the problem.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware? Are you happy? Now, can you please answer my question?

Comment: Yes.  I can try. In your corrected code you have one `session_start()` with `ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.progressiveai.org')` in front of it. As I stated before you need to correct the domain before every `session_start()` in your code base. Please actually test the exact code first before you put it in your question.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, it doesn't work. Can we use a Logout Script to completely wipe out any and destroy all the Sessions and Cookies? I already have this: `<?php session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
header("Location: https://auth.progressiveai.org");
?>` But it will only work on the Sub-Domain and not the Main Domain. Any ideas on who to make the Logout Script also destroy sessions on the Main Domain?

Answer (score -1):

After a lot of thought and tests I ran, I found an answer!

Setting the session cookie on the Sub-Domain:

```php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['SESSION_EMAIL'])) {
    // Set SESSION_EMAIL in the session
    $_SESSION['SESSION_EMAIL'] = $email;
    
    // Set a session cookie for all subdomains of progressiveai.org
    $session_email = $_SESSION['SESSION_EMAIL'];
    setcookie('SESSION_EMAIL', $session_email, 0, '/', '.progressiveai.org');

    // Redirect to the desired location
    header("Location: https://auth.progressiveai.org/redirect");
    die();
}
```

Using the session cookie on the Main Domain:

```php
session_start(); // Start or resume the session
if (!isset($_SESSION['SESSION_EMAIL']) && isset($_COOKIE['SESSION_EMAIL'])) {
    // Retrieve SESSION_EMAIL from the cookie if it's not in the session
    $_SESSION['SESSION_EMAIL'] = $_COOKIE['SESSION_EMAIL'];
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['SESSION_EMAIL'])) {
    header("Location: https://auth.progressiveai.org");
    die();
}
```

This code will set a session cookie named SESSION_EMAIL that is accessible across all subdomains of the Main Domain and then retrieve it from the Main Domain if it's not found in the session.

Comment: If you can read _that_ cookie, set from the subdomain, on the main domain - then you should be able to read a cookie with a session ID in the same way, provided it was set using the same parameters. I'm guessing your problem likely has to do with what SAMESITE value your session id cookie got set with.